# Joining discontinuous skeleton shapes and discontinuous lines

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, shapes, pattern-recognition

I have a binary image, I want to detect discontinuous lines and linking them. 
I don't know anything (coordinates, angle etc). 
Can any one guide me how should I start? Suppose I have this image:

[image]

I want to join discontinuous lines. And I want to store information of lines joining (in an array) to use afterward.

Comment: You can start with some sort of line detection algorithm: http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/gjmr-lsd/

or Matlab's Hough-lines function.

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem interesting and I will try to give you just some ideas but unfortunately not a complete algorithm (you know, it takes time...). I will also leave you with some unanswered questions.

I consider the image you posted as a binary image, that is the black pixels have value of zero and the white pixels have value of one. I ignore the red pixels because I think you drew them in order to highlight where you would like to connect the broken lines; ignoring the red pixels means I will set their value to zero.

First of all we need some definitions.

A non-border pixel has 8 neighbor (north-west, north, north-east, east, south-east, south, south-west, west) pixels:

```
abc
h*d
gfe
```

in the above diagram the pixel is indicated by `*` and its 8 neighbor by `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` and `h`.

I define an *endpoint pixel* as a pixel with value of one and just one neighbor with value of one, the remaining neighbor have a value of zero, so for example this diagram shows an endpoint pixel

```
000
011
000
```

because `d=1` and all the remaining neighbors are zero.
The following diagram shows instead a pixel which is not and endpoint pixel because it has two neighbors equal to one (`a=1` and `e=1`)

```
100
010
001
```

Now we can start to describe a part of a simple algorithm.

In the first step find all the endpoint pixels and put them in a vector: in the following image I marked the endpoints from 1 to 15 (note that the endpoint 15 was not highlighted in the image you posted).

[image]

In the second step, for each endpoint, find its closest endpoint: for example consider the endpoint 4, its closest endpoint is 5. Now, if you follow the simple rule of connecting one endpoint with its closest endpoint you will have segments connecting 4-5, 10-11, 13-14, which are all fine. But consider 1: its closest endpoint is 2 or maybe it is 3, but I would like that the algorithm just connected 2 and 3 while connecting 1 to the leftmost vertical line. I would also like the same behavior for 6, 9 and 12.

Now a different situation: what about 6, 7 and 8? Ignore for a moment 8, the closest endpoint of 6 is then 7 but they are already connected, how we can manage this case?

And, last, consider 15: why did not highlight it in the image you posted? Maybe it should be ignored?

Comment: thank you for your responses, reasoning that you proposed is clear but I think he cannot handle all cases which may be presents. So to answer your question case 15 it will be ignored and I don't know how we can manage this case 1,6, 9 and 12. I think an improvement your reasoning and how we can manage all cases

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help.

1. Increase the thickness of the lines to at-least 2.
2. Find those runs of consecutive foreground pixel in vertical direction in the image whose previous or next column has all background pixel within the run-length. This would give the location of the points, which needs to be processed.
3. For each point find the nearest steep point. This would be either a [branch point](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MorphologicalBranchPoints.html) or a point where an abrupt change in angle has occured. (Example point 15 in the image of previous answer). If there is no such point there is obviously another `end-point`. Call these as `reference point`. The vector between an endpoint and reference point would give the direction of extension.
4. Now there can be various ways to decide which point to join with. You can take the nearest foreground point in that direction. You can also pick some features depending on the angle and distance between an endpoint and a point of extension to use in a KNN classifier.

Hope it helps.

Comment: to be frank I do not know how I could implement this but thank you very much for your response

Comment: Routines Detecting branch points, end points are available in matlab. And getting the reference points might be easier after deleting the branch points.